# Conditional rendering of string var

Tags: reactjs, string, react-native, conditional-statements, var

As shown below, I have a text that renders text in this manner.

address, additionalInfo

```
<Text subtitle gray>
  {address} ", "
  {additionalInfo}
</Text>
```

However I want to re-write it so that the text will render

address, (line break)
additionalInfo

But if {additionalInfo}=null I want it to render

address

^without the linebreak.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ```{additionalInfo? `${address}, ${additionalInfo}` :address }```?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure why it didn't show the line break my question above. But to clarify, I want it to be like this - address, (new line below) additionalInfo

Answer (score 1):

A better practice will be to always check if variable is set or not.

```
<Text subtitle gray>
{address ? address : ""} ", "
{additionalInfo ? additionalInfo : ""}
</Text>
```

Comment: Your solution will always show ", " regardless of whether either variables exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Text subtitle gray>
 {additionalInfo
     ? `${address} ,${additionalInfo}` 
     : `${address} ${additionalInfo}`
 }
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you DO want the line break if both variables exist, correct?

```
<Text subtitle gray>
  {!additionalInfo ? address : `${address},\n${additionalInfo}` }
</Text>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for the opposite. So if {additionalInfo}=null then there is no linebreak.

Comment: @rbq10 Yes precisely. 
If [NO additionalInfo && YES address] => NO Linebreak <-- Other answerers are focusing on this
If [YES additionalInfo && YES address] => YES Linebreak <-- This is what I am asking you about. Do you want the linebreak or not. Cause other answers are not addressing this part.

Comment: Yes you are correct @Ziwon. If [NO additionalInfo && YES address] => NO Linebreak

Comment: All the answers so far are not what I was looking for. Not sure how much more clearer I can be aha